# Pop the view controller to a non-existent view controller

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app which has a LoginViewController and a DashboardViewController. If the user successfully logs in, he/she is taken to the DashboardViewController.

The LoginViewController has a *Remember Me* option. If the user ticks it on when logging in, that value is stored in NSUserDefaults to be used for subsequent log ins. For example, if the user turns the *Remember Me* option on when loggin in, the next time the user opens the app, he/she is taken to the DashboardViewController directly without ever showing the LoginViewController.

Here's the storyboard structure I have.

[image]

In the AppDelegate, I set the window's rootViewController depending on the saved NSUserDefaults value.

```
if !NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(Globals.IsLoggedIn) {
    // Show login screen
    let loginViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
} else {
    // Show Dashboard
    let dashboardViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()).instantiateInitialViewController()!
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashboardViewController)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
}
```

It all works well. The problem is when I have to log out.

In the navigationbar in the DashboardViewController, there's a UIBarButtonItem that logs you out when tapped and confirmed.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: "Are you sure you want to logout?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: Globals.IsLoggedIn)
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}))
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If the user logs in from the LoginViewController, move to the DashboardViewController and logs out, the DashboardViewController pops out of the navigation stack and the LoginViewController appears. All good.

But say I had the Remember Me option turned on in a previous log in and I open the app. Now I'm taken to the DashboardViewController directly. Notice how the navigationController embedding the DashboardViewController is set as the window's rootViewController.

So if I now log out, there is no instance of the LoginViewController to pop back to because it was never added in the first place!

How do I resolve this scenario? Is there a way to secretly instantiate an instance of LoginViewController even when directly showing the DashboardViewController directly, but silently add it to the navigation stack but still show the DashboardViewController as the first view controller or something?

Or would you recommend a different approach, architecture overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.insert(vc!, atIndex: 0) // at the beginning
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: That's a neat trick. I [modified](http://pastie.org/10589772) my code based on your solution and it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, feels good when you learn how to use the available tools.